# Given a list of lists in Prolog, how to apply a clause on each list?

Tags: recursion, prolog

Given the following clauses

```
nth_member(0, [Elem|_Tail], Elem):-!.
nth_member(Index, _List, _Elem):- Index < 0, !, fail.
nth_member(Index, [_Head|Tail], Elem):-NextIndex is Index - 1, nth0(NextIndex, Tail, Elem).

checkGoal(F,Res):- implies(F, Res), implies(Res, F), !.

checkInList(P, Q, R, H, F, R):- nth_member(0, H, P), nth_member(1, H, Q), nth_member(2, H, R), write(F), checkGoal(F, R).

loop([]).
loop(P, Q, R, [H|T], F, R) :- checkInList(P, Q, R, H, F,R), loop(T).

seeEachVal(P, Q, R, F, R):- tvals(X), loop(P, Q, R, X, F, R).

tvals(List):- List = [[t, t, t], [t, t, f], [t, f, t],
                [t, f, f], [f, t, t], [f, t, f],
                [f, f, t], [f, f, f]].
```

Here is the output of what I am getting after running the following query:

```
?- seeEachVal(P, Q, R, or(or(P,Q),R),t).

seeEachVal(P, Q, R, or(or(P,Q),R),t).
     45    8  Call: seeEachVal(_1719,_1720,_1721,or(or(_1719,_1720),_1721),t) ? 
     46    9  Call: tvals(_1814) ? 
     46    9  Exit: tvals([[t,t,t],[t,t,f],[t,f,t],[t,f,f],[f,t,t],[f,t,...],[f,...],[...]]) ? 
     47    9  Call: loop(_1719,_1720,_1721,[[t,t,t],[t,t,f],[t,f,t],[t,f,f],[f,t,t],[f,t,...],[f,...],[...]],and(or(_1719,_1720),_1721),t) ? 
     48   10  Call: checkInList(_1719,_1720,_1721,[t,t,t],and(or(_1719,_1720),_1721),t) ? 
     49   11  Call: nth_member(0,[t,t,t],_1719) ? 
     49   11  Exit: nth_member(0,[t,t,t],t) ? 
     50   11  Call: nth_member(1,[t,t,t],_1720) ? 
     51   12  Call: 1<0 ? 
     51   12  Fail: 1<0 ? 
     51   12  Call: _2013 is 1-1 ? 
     51   12  Exit: 0 is 1-1 ? 
     52   12  Call: nth0(0,[t,t],_1720) ? 
     52   12  Exit: nth0(0,[t,t],t) ? 
     50   11  Exit: nth_member(1,[t,t,t],t) ? 
     53   11  Call: nth_member(2,[t,t,t],_1721) ? 
     54   12  Call: 2<0 ? 
     54   12  Fail: 2<0 ? 
     54   12  Call: _2093 is 2-1 ? 
     54   12  Exit: 1 is 2-1 ? 
     55   12  Call: nth0(1,[t,t],_1721) ? 
     55   12  Exit: nth0(1,[t,t],t) ? 
     53   11  Exit: nth_member(2,[t,t,t],t) ? 
     56   11  Call: write(and(or(t,t),t)) ? 
and(or(t,t),t)
     56   11  Exit: write(and(or(t,t),t)) ? 
     57   11  Call: checkGoal(and(or(t,t),t),t) ? 
     58   12  Call: or(t=t,t=f) ? 
     59   13  Call: '$call'(t=t,or,2,true) ? 
     60   14  Call: t=t ? 
     60   14  Exit: t=t ? 
     59   13  Exit: '$call'(t=t,or,2,true) ? 
     58   12  Exit: or(t=t,t=f) ? 
     61   12  Call: implies(or(or(t,t),t),t) ? 
     62   13  Call: or(not(or(or(t,t),t)),t) ? 
     63   14  Call: '$call'(not(and(or(t,t),t)),or,2,true) ? 
     64   15  Call: not(or(or(t,t),t)) ? 
     65   16  Call: \+or(or(t,t),t) ? 
     66   17  Call: or(or(t,t),t) ? 
     67   18  Call: '$call'(or(t,t),and,2,true) ? 
     68   19  Call: or(t,t) ? 
     69   20  Call: '$call'(t,or,2,true) ? 
     70   21  Call: t ? 
     70   21  Exit: t ? 
     69   20  Exit: '$call'(t,or,2,true) ? 
     68   19  Exit: or(t,t) ? 
     67   18  Exit: '$call'(or(t,t),and,2,true) ? 
     71   18  Call: '$call'(t,and,2,true) ? 
     72   19  Call: t ? 
     72   19  Exit: t ? 
     71   18  Exit: '$call'(t,and,2,true) ? 
     66   17  Exit: and(or(t,t),t) ? 
     65   16  Fail: \+and(or(t,t),t) ? 
     64   15  Fail: not(and(or(t,t),t)) ? 
     63   14  Fail: '$call'(not(and(or(t,t),t)),or,2,true) ? 
     63   14  Call: '$call'(t,or,2,true) ? 
     64   15  Call: t ? 
     64   15  Exit: t ? 
     63   14  Exit: '$call'(t,or,2,true) ? 
     62   13  Exit: or(not((or(t,t),t)),t) ? 
     61   12  Exit: implies(or(or(t,t),t),t) ? 
     65   12  Call: implies(t,or(or(t,t),t)) ? 
     66   13  Call: or(not(t),or(or(t,t),t)) ? 
     67   14  Call: '$call'(not(t),or,2,true) ? 
     68   15  Call: not(t) ? 
     69   16  Call: \+t ? 
     70   17  Call: t ? 
     70   17  Exit: t ? 
     69   16  Fail: \+t ? 
     68   15  Fail: not(t) ? 
     67   14  Fail: '$call'(not(t),or,2,true) ? 
     67   14  Call: '$call'(and(or(t,t),t),or,2,true) ? 
     68   15  Call: or(or(t,t),t) ? 
     69   16  Call: '$call'(or(t,t),and,2,true) ? 
     70   17  Call: or(t,t) ? 
     71   18  Call: '$call'(t,or,2,true) ? 
     72   19  Call: t ? 
     72   19  Exit: t ? 
     71   18  Exit: '$call'(t,or,2,true) ? 
     70   17  Exit: or(t,t) ? 
     69   16  Exit: '$call'(or(t,t),and,2,true) ? 
     73   16  Call: '$call'(t,and,2,true) ? 
     74   17  Call: t ? 
     74   17  Exit: t ? 
     73   16  Exit: '$call'(t,and,2,true) ? 
     68   15  Exit: and(or(t,t),t) ? 
     67   14  Exit: '$call'(or(or(t,t),t),or,2,true) ? 
     66   13  Exit: or(not(t),or(or(t,t),t)) ? 
     65   12  Exit: implies(t,or(or(t,t),t)) ? 
     57   11  Exit: checkAssignment(and(or(t,t),t),t) ? 
     48   10  Exit: checkInList(t,t,t,[t,t,t],and(or(t,t),t),t) ? 
     75   10  Call: loop([[t,t,f],[t,f,t],[t,f,f],[f,t,t],[f,t,f],[f,f,...],[f,...]]) ? 
     75   10  Fail: loop([[t,t,f],[t,f,t],[t,f,f],[f,t,t],[f,t,f],[f,f,...],[f,...]]) ? 
     47    9  Fail: loop(_1719,_1720,_1721,[[t,t,t],[t,t,f],[t,f,t],[t,f,f],[f,t,t],[f,t,...],[f,...],[...]],and(or(_1719,_1720),_1721),t) ? 
     45    8  Fail: seeEachVal(_1719,_1720,_1721,or(or(_1719,_1720),_1721),t) ?
```

As you can see, the list has moved one index, but Prolog halted the ensuing operation.
How can I make other iterations run as well, without Prolog stopping at the first iteration?

---

UPDATED

Given a list of truth values

```
tvals(List):- List = [[t, t, t], [t, t, f], [t, f, t],
                [t, f, f], [f, t, t], [f, t, f],
                [f, f, t], [f, f, f]].
```

and the following clauses

```
checkGoal(F,Res):- implies(F, Res), implies(Res, F), !.

getRes(P, Q, R, F, Res):- tvals(X), seeEachVal(P, Q, R, X, F, Res).
```

I am trying to run `seeEachVal(...)` on every list in `tvals`. My final goal is to see `P, Q, R` when `checkGoal` gets satisfied given a user input F and desiderata R, but I only manage to get through one iteration. F can only contain variables, while R can only be t or f.

Here is the output of what I am getting after running the following query:

```
?- getRes(P, Q, R, or(or(P,Q),R),t).

      1    1  Call: getRes(_426,_427,_428,and(or(_426,_427),_428),t) ? 
      2    2  Call: tvals(_521) ? 
      2    2  Exit: tvals([[t,t,t],[t,t,f],[t,f,t],[t,f,f],[f,t,t],[f,t,...],[f,...],[...]]) ? 
      3    2  Call: seeEachVal(_426,_427,_428,[[t,t,t],[t,t,f],[t,f,t],[t,f,f],[f,t,t],[f,t,...],[f,...],[...]],and(or(_426,_427),_428),t) ? 
      4    3  Call: checkGoal(and(or(t,t),t),t) ? 
      5    4  Call: or(t=t,t=f) ? 
      6    5  Call: '$call'(t=t,or,2,true) ? 
      7    6  Call: t=t ? 
      7    6  Exit: t=t ? 
      6    5  Exit: '$call'(t=t,or,2,true) ? 
      5    4  Exit: or(t=t,t=f) ? 
      8    4  Call: implies(or(or(t,t),t),t) ? 
      9    5  Call: or(not(or(or(t,t),t)),t) ? 
     10    6  Call: '$call'(not(and(or(t,t),t)),or,2,true) ? 
     11    7  Call: not(or(or(t,t),t)) ? 
     12    8  Call: \+or(or(t,t),t) ? 
     13    9  Call: or(or(t,t),t) ? 
     14   10  Call: '$call'(or(t,t),and,2,true) ? 
     15   11  Call: or(t,t) ? 
     16   12  Call: '$call'(t,or,2,true) ? 
     17   13  Call: t ? 
     17   13  Exit: t ? 
     16   12  Exit: '$call'(t,or,2,true) ? 
     15   11  Exit: or(t,t) ? 
     14   10  Exit: '$call'(or(t,t),and,2,true) ? 
     18   10  Call: '$call'(t,and,2,true) ? 
     19   11  Call: t ? 
     19   11  Exit: t ? 
     18   10  Exit: '$call'(t,and,2,true) ? 
     13    9  Exit: or(or(t,t),t) ? 
     12    8  Fail: \+or(or(t,t),t) ? 
     11    7  Fail: not(or(or(t,t),t)) ? 
     10    6  Fail: '$call'(not(or(or(t,t),t)),or,2,true) ? 
     10    6  Call: '$call'(t,or,2,true) ? 
     11    7  Call: t ? 
     11    7  Exit: t ? 
     10    6  Exit: '$call'(t,or,2,true) ? 
      9    5  Exit: or(not(and(or(t,t),t)),t) ? 
      8    4  Exit: implies(and(or(t,t),t),t) ? 
     12    4  Call: implies(t,and(or(t,t),t)) ? 
     13    5  Call: or(not(t),and(or(t,t),t)) ? 
     14    6  Call: '$call'(not(t),or,2,true) ? 
     15    7  Call: not(t) ? 
     16    8  Call: \+t ? 
     17    9  Call: t ? 
     17    9  Exit: t ? 
     16    8  Fail: \+t ? 
     15    7  Fail: not(t) ? 
     14    6  Fail: '$call'(not(t),or,2,true) ? 
     14    6  Call: '$call'(and(or(t,t),t),or,2,true) ? 
     15    7  Call: and(or(t,t),t) ? 
     16    8  Call: '$call'(or(t,t),and,2,true) ? 
     17    9  Call: or(t,t) ? 
     18   10  Call: '$call'(t,or,2,true) ? 
     19   11  Call: t ? 
     19   11  Exit: t ? 
     18   10  Exit: '$call'(t,or,2,true) ? 
     17    9  Exit: or(t,t) ? 
     16    8  Exit: '$call'(or(t,t),and,2,true) ? 
     20    8  Call: '$call'(t,and,2,true) ? 
     21    9  Call: t ? 
     21    9  Exit: t ? 
     20    8  Exit: '$call'(t,and,2,true) ? 
     15    7  Exit: and(or(t,t),t) ? 
     14    6  Exit: '$call'(and(or(t,t),t),or,2,true) ? 
     13    5  Exit: or(not(t),and(or(t,t),t)) ? 
     12    4  Exit: implies(t,and(or(t,t),t)) ? 
      4    3  Exit: checkGoal(and(or(t,t),t),t) ? 
     22    3  Call: write([t,t,t]) ? 
[t,t,t]
     22    3  Exit: write([t,t,t]) ? 
     23    3  Call: seeEachVal([[t,t,f],[t,f,t],[t,f,f],[f,t,t],[f,t,f],[f,f,...],[f,...]]) ? 
     23    3  Fail: seeEachVal([[t,t,f],[t,f,t],[t,f,f],[f,t,t],[f,t,f],[f,f,...],[f,...]]) ? 
      4    3  Call: seeEachVal([[t,t,f],[t,f,t],[t,f,f],[f,t,t],[f,t,f],[f,f,...],[f,...]]) ? 
      4    3  Fail: seeEachVal([[t,t,f],[t,f,t],[t,f,f],[f,t,t],[f,t,f],[f,f,...],[f,...]]) ? 
      3    2  Fail: seeEachVal(_426,_427,_428,[[t,t,t],[t,t,f],[t,f,t],[t,f,f],[f,t,t],[f,t,...],[f,...],[...]],and(or(_426,_427),_428),t) ? 
      1    1  Fail: getRes(_426,_427,_428,and(or(_426,_427),_428),t) ?
```

As you can see, the list has moved one index, but Prolog halted the ensuing operation.
How can I make other iterations run as well, without Prolog stopping at the first iteration?

---

SOLUTION UPDATE

```
checkGoal(F,R):- implies(F, R), implies(R, F), !.

seeEachVal([]).
seeEachVal(P,Q,R,[[P1,Q1,R1]|Ts], Formula, Result) :-
    (
        (   P = P1, Q = Q1, R = R1,
            checkGoal(Formula, Result),
            write([P,Q,R])
        );
        true
    ),
    seeEachVal(P,Q,R,Ts, Formula, Result).


getRes(P, Q, R, F, R):- tvals(X), seeEachVal(P, Q, R, X, F, R).
```

Answer (score 0):

It feels to me that you're over complicating this a bit.

Let's just start with the facts:

```
implies(t,t).
implies(f,t).
implies(f,f).

tvals(
[
    [t,t,t],[t,t,f],[t,f,t],[t,f,f],
    [f,t,t],[f,t,f],[f,f,t],[f,f,f]
]).
```

Now you just need two clauses:

```
seeEachVal([]).
seeEachVal([[P,Q,R]|Ts]) :-
    (
        (
            implies(P,Q),
            implies(Q,R),
            write([P,Q,R]),
            nl
        );
        true
    ),
    seeEachVal(Ts).
```

We're stopping on the empty list. We're trying to find which rules match our `implies` requirements. Then just iterate the remainder of the list if the `implies` rules fail.

I couldn't quite grasp how you were trying to get the `implies` rules to work from your code, so I guessed.

I run this like this:

```
?- tvals(L), seeEachVal(L).
```

I get this result:

```
[t,t,t]
[f,t,t]
[f,f,t]
[f,f,f]
L = [[t, t, t], [t, t, f], [t, f, t], [t, f, f], [f, t, t], [f, t, f], [f, f|...], [f|...]].
```

Comment: My bad on the implies clause. I have edited it. 

What about this specific query? There is something I do not understand. I need to see which values of this formula F to evaluate to result R: in which cases does and(or(P,Q),R) evaluates to T? The implies rule is used for general purposes. Formulas are not hardcoded inside. Neither are the desiderata result.

Comment: I need to be able to insert each P,Q,R in F.

Comment: What does "insert each P,Q,R in F" mean?

Comment: I updated the code. Is it clearer now?

Comment: @JJKam - You need to make sure your predicates have the same arity - you have `seeEachVal/1` & `seeEachVal/6`. You are also calling `checkGoal` on two unbound variables.

Comment: @JJKam - Also, please don't edit your question to wipe out parts that people have used to already answer your question. Add any new information to the bottom. I've updated the question for you.

Comment: @JJKam - And finally, no, it's not clearer. What does "insert each P,Q,R in F" mean?

Comment: That means that P,Q,R stand for some truth values in formula F. With three variables I get 8 possible combinations of truth values. Need to automatically print the values of P,Q,R when the desired truth value is equivalent to the evaluation of the Formula F with the replaced truth values. Better now?

Comment: After changing the arity, the program works. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JJKam - You're saying you want to the `Result` variable to bind to the result of passing each of `P`, `Q`, and `R` through the `chckGoal/2` predicate?

Comment: @JJKam - Please post your working code as an answer to your question.

Comment: @JJKam - Please don't accept my answer. It doesn't answer your question. Please post your solution.